# How to kill a program by the hard way, only if it refuses to terminate the soft way?

Tags: linux, bash, signals

**How to exit a program by bash on a soft way and if this was not successful do it on a hard way.**

- Its known how to open a programm by bash and how to get the PID of the programm. The follow sample open the editor XED:

  xed & PID=$!
- Its known how to echo the PID of the program what was opened:

  echo $PID

  12345 # sample output of a PID
- Its known how to try to close a program on a soft way and how to select the program by PID for this:

  kill -15 $PID # select a program by PID and tray to kill it on a soft way
- Its known how to close a program on a hard way and how to select the program by PID for this:

  kill -9 $PID # select a program by PID and kill it on a hard way

Put all together what I have, a still missing something:

```
xed & PID=$! # open the program xed and get the pid
echo PID of programm: $PID

sleep 5 # lets run the xed 5 seconds

kill -15 $PID # select the xed by PID and try to kill it on soft way

# check based on variant 1, 2, 3 or other, the xed was sucessfull killed on soft way or not
# if the xed still running, kill it on follow way

kill -9 $PID # select the xed by PID and kill it on hard way
```

Comment: It's too bad the `wait` builtin doesn't have a timeout argument.

Comment: It can be it make sence to close a program hard, after it dosnt close on soft way within 2 or 5 s.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Based one Answer of Eddy763, the follow Logically better fitting variant:

```
xed & PID=$! # Start XED and get PID

sleep 2

# kill -15 $PID # Soft Kill, activate or deactivate for testing
echo
echo

sleep 2

if ! ps -p $PID
then
    echo "The PID/program are closed successful by Soft Kill"

else
    echo "The PID/program didn't be killed successful by Soft Kill active, so it will be killed now on hard way"
    kill -9 $PID # Hard Kill

fi
echo
echo
```

Answer (score 0):

```
#!/bin/bash

xed & PID=$! # Start XED and get PID

sleep 3

# kill -15 $PID # Soft Kill, activate or deactivate for testing
echo
echo

sleep 3

if ps -p $PID
then
    echo "The PID/program didn't be killed successful by Soft Kill"
    kill -9 $PID # Hard Kill
else
    echo "PID/program are already closed by Soft Kill"

fi
echo
echo
```

Answer (score 0):

You can get the information about the process still running on follow way:

```
xed & xedPid=$! # Start of editor XED and asking for PID
[1] 12345
kill -15 $PID


# getting the follow, if the XED was killed successfull soft before:
kill -15 $PID
bash: kill: (12345) - Kein passender Prozess gefunden
**[1]+  Beendet                 xed**
```

Answer (score 0):

You can get the information about the process are still running or not, on follow way too:

```
xed & xedPid=$! # Start of editor XED and asking for PID
[1] 12345

# Output if xed are running
kill -0 $PID
kill: Aufruf: kill [-s Signalname | -n Signalnummer | -Signalname] pid | jobspec ... oder kill -l [Signalname]

kill -15 $PID

# Output if XED are not more running:
kill -0 $PID
kill: Aufruf: kill [-s Signalname | -n Signalnummer | -Signalname] pid | jobspec ... oder kill -l [Signalname]
**[1]+  Beendet                 xed**
```

Answer (score 0):

kill -15 $PID
sleep 1

if ps -p $PID > /dev/null
then
kill -9 $PID
fi